# Create a read-only calendar with Microsoft Graph API

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

Using the following code

```
var calendarToCreate = new Calendar
{
    Name = "My read-only calendar",
    CanEdit = false,
    IsRemovable = false,
};

await graphClient
    .Users["my@email.com"]
    .Calendars
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(calendarToCreate);
```

the created calendar has `CanEdit` and `IsRemovable` both set to `true` instead of `false`.

What am I doing wrong?

### Update

As @Danstan pointed out, the doc says "This property is true for the user who created the calendar. This property is also true for a user who has been shared a calendar and granted write access.".
Especially the second part is interesting: The property is true for the user the calendar has been shared with (with write access).

This begs the question: How do I create a calendar on a user (`my@email.com`) without giving this user write access?

Comment: As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/calendar?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties), CanEdit  will be true as long as you are the creator of the calendar. Have you tried to view or fetch the calendar as the user who should have readOnly? This value will only be false for the user on whole mailbox the calendar is created.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. Could you please read my update on the question and respond to it, if you know something about that?

Comment: I have checked your scenario and the field CanEdit  seems to be false only when the calendar is shared with view only access. In your case when you say read only, do you mean shared because, if you create the calendar on another user, that use is the owner. If you need a read only calendar on a user, you may just need to share/delegate with read only access.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I would have to create the calendar on (technical) user A, so I can share that calendar with (actual) user B with read-only access, so that canEdit will be false.
Our problem: We want to create read-only calendars for every employee on a tenant. Can a (technical) user hold all those calendars (for alle the other employees)?